# How to use recursive formula in loop and if statement

Tags: r, recursion, matrix, formula, recursive-datastructures

I may be overcomplicating this problem.

The problem is as such

Variables

```
a = lower triangular matrix/dataframe 20x20 
b = a 1x20 matrix/vector 
c = the previous row result of the formula (recursive bit)
```

I want to have a lower triangular matrix (I,j) where it is recursively defined that

*pseudocode*

`if(I<j) = 0`

`else if (I==j) = 1`

`else (I>j) = sum(a * b * c )/ b[I] - b[J]`  (where I is current row position and J is current column position)

Example of how I hope the formula/ R's vectorisation will work shown on a smaller matrix to make life easier.

I = row

j = column

b(I,j)

b(1,2) refers to position in matrix

*Pseudo code of example matrix*

```
    Matrix C
         1                                                                       |  2                                                                    |3  |4  |5  |6  |
    1|i=j=1                                                                      |i<j=0                                                                  |...|...|...|...| 
    2|i>j=a(2,1)*b(1)*c(1,1)/b(2)-b(1)                                           |i=j=1                                                                  |...|...|...|...|
    3|i>j= (a(3,1)*b(1)*c(1,1) + a(3,2)*b(2)*c(2,1))/(b(3)-b(1)                  |i>j= a(3,2)*b(2)*c(2,2)/(b(3)-b(2)                                     |...|...|...|...|
    4|i>j = a(4,1)*b(1)*c(1,1)+a(4,2)*b(2)*c(2,1)+a(4,3)*b(3)*c(3,1))/b(4)-b(1)  |i>j= a(4,2)*b(2)*c(2,2) + a(4,3)*b(3)*c(3,2)/b(4)-b(2)                 |...|...|...|...|
    5|...                                                                        |...                                                                    |...|...|...|...|
    6|...                                                                        |...                                                                    |...|...|...|...|
```

Onto the code I have so far,

Create variable first as shown below:

```
    my_int <- 20
    
    nr <- as.integer(my_int)
    
    #create a n x n matrix with zeroes 
    
    a <- matrix(0, nr, nr)
    
    # For each row and for each column, assign values based on position
    
    # These values are the product of two indexes
    
    for(i in 1:dim(a)[1]) {
      for(j in 1:dim(a)[2]) {
        a[i,j] = if(i<j) {
          0
        }else if(i==j) {
          1
        }else {
          3
        }
        }
        }
    
    # make into dataframe
    
    mymat <- data.frame(mymat)
    
    # create b variable
    
    z <- rep(1:20)
    
    # made it into lower diagonal matrix to make it easier to work with
    
    b <- matrix(0, length(z), length(z))
    b[lower.tri(b, diag = TRUE)] <- z[sequence(length(z):1)]
    b
    
    # create matrix for formula to operate with 
    
    # create variable "c"
    
    
    c <- matrix(0, nr, nr)
    
    # For each row and for each column, assign values based on position
    # These values are the product of two indexes
    for(i in 1:dim(c)[1]) {
      for(j in 1:dim(c)[2]) {
        mymat2[i,j] = if(i<j) {
          0
        }else if(i==j) {
          1
        }else {
          5 # place holder for now
        }
        }
        }
```

Formula for calculating results, I think works thanks to R's vectorisation

```
    sum(a*b*lag(c), na.rm = TRUE)/(b[,j]-b[I,])
```

My issue is then how to insert this in the if statements for the creation of the recursively defined matrix as shown below

```
    # calculate recursively defined lower triangular matrix
    
    c <- matrix(0, nr, nr)
    
    # For each row and for each column, assign values based on position
    # These values are the product of two indexes
    for(i in 1:dim(c)[1]) {
      for(j in 1:dim(c)[2]) {
        mymat2[i,j] = if(i<j) {
          0
        }else if(i==j) {
          1
        }else {
          sum(a*b*lag(c), na.rm = TRUE)/(b[,j]-b[I,]) # formula for calculation of values for lower triangular matrix
        }
        }
        }
```

This gives error

`Error in mymat2[i, j] <- if (i < j) { :  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

I can link an excel spreadsheet where this formula works if it would help. It is only achievable in excel by a lot of manual inputs etc.

Example of expected results using real data

```
a = 5x5 lower triangle matrix

0|0   |0   |0   |0
5|0   |0   |0   |0
5|0.56|0   |0   |0
5|0.20|0.61|0   |0
5|0.06|0.16|0.61|0


b = 1x5 matrix/vector

0.27917|0.499|0.83|1.191|1.48

c = recursive matrix results

1   |0   |0   |0   |0
6.36|1   |0   |0   |0
5.77|0.84|1   |0   |0
5.50|0.77|1.43|1   |0
5.3 |0.72|1.80|2.46|1
```

Example of how I calculated "c" in excel

```
1   |0   |0   |0   |0

=(INDEX(a,2,1)*INDEX(b,1)*INDEX(c,1,1))/(INDEX(b,2)-INDEX(b,1))|1   |0   |0   |0

=(INDEX(a,3,1)*INDEX(b,1)*INDEX(c,1,1)+INDEX(a,3,2)*INDEX(b,2)*INDEX(c,2,1))/(INDEX(b,3)-INDEX(b,1))|=(INDEX(a,3,2)*INDEX(b,2)*INDEX(c,2,2))/(INDEX(b,3)-INDEX(b,2))|1   |0   |0

=(INDEX(a,4,1)*INDEX(b,1)*INDEX(c,1,1)+INDEX(a,4,2)*INDEX(b,2)*INDEX(c,2,1)+INDEX(a,4,3)*INDEX(b,3)*INDEX(c,3,1))/(INDEX(b,4)-INDEX(b,1))|=(INDEX(a,4,2)*INDEX(b,2)*INDEX(c,2,2)+INDEX(a,4,3)*INDEX(b,3)*INDEX(c,3,2))/(INDEX(b,4)-INDEX(b,2))|=(INDEX(a,4,3)*INDEX(b,3)*INDEX(c,3,3))/(INDEX(b,4)-INDEX(b,3))|1   |0

=(INDEX(a,5,1)*INDEX(b,1)*INDEX(c,1,1)+INDEX(a,5,2)*INDEX(b,2)*INDEX(c,2,1)+INDEX(a,5,3)*INDEX(b,3)*INDEX(c,3,1)+INDEX(a,5,4)*INDEX(b,4)*INDEX(c,4,1))/(INDEX(b,5)-INDEX(b,1)) |=(INDEX(a,5,2)*INDEX(b,2)*INDEX(c,2,2)+INDEX(a,5,3)*INDEX(b,3)*INDEX(c,3,2)+INDEX(a,5,4)*INDEX(b,4)*INDEX(c,4,2))/(INDEX(b,5)-INDEX(b,2))|=(INDEX(a,5,3)*INDEX(b,3)*INDEX(c,3,3)+INDEX(a,5,4)*INDEX(b,4)*INDEX(c,4,3))/(INDEX(b,5)-INDEX(b,3))|=(INDEX(a,5,4)*INDEX(b,4)*INDEX(c,4,4))/(INDEX(b,5)-INDEX(b,4))|1
```

Above code shows how it can be calculated in excel via index and manually setting a large amount of cell positions.

Comment: In your matrix, could you fix cell(4,2) and also show what cell(4,1) should look like?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a 5x5 matrix with intended output. I am not sure if your ```sum(...)``` line is doing what you hope it to do. Also, the denominator in the ```sum(...)``` line will make the result a vector of length 20 in your example. The error is that ```mymat2[i, j]``` should only be assigned one value but this would assign 20.

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting, I've made the changes and added an example of the data. @CPak I've corrected (4,2) thanks for finding that and added in (4,1).

Comment: @Cole I've added an example of what the data should do. I think you correct about the sum, interpreted that wrongly.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see how it is generalized. Not sure if this is linear algebra you are doing, but using terms associated with that. Finally, some of your initial code to demonstrate making a matrix could be simplified to ```n = 5L; mat = diag(n); mat[lower.tri(mat)] = 3```. Good luck with the rest of your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possibly dynamic programming(?) solution. I've only verified a few 'cells' so you'll need to verify that it's giving results you expected.

```
# FUNCTIONS
vpad <- function(vec) { 
    extend <- 20 - length(vec)
    c(vec, rep(0, extend))
}

clip <- function(x) { x[x >= 0 & x <= 20] }

pad_a <- function(a, iter) {
    mat <- cbind(a[, iter:20], matrix(0, 20, iter-1))
    mat * lower.tri(mat)
}

pad_b <- function(b, iter) {
    tmp <- vpad(b[iter:20])
    mat <- matrix(rep(tmp, each=20), 20, 20)
    mat * lower.tri(mat)
}

pad_c <- function(c, iter) {
    L <- 21 - iter
    i <- clip(seq(L) + iter - 1)
    j <- seq(i)
    v <- vpad(mapply(function(i, j) c[i, j], i, j))
    mat <- matrix(rep(v, each=20), 20, 20)
    mat <- mat * (lower.tri(mat) + diag(20))
    mat

    end <- 21 - iter
    mat1 <- rbind(matrix(0, iter - 1, 20), mat[1:end, ])
    mat1 * lower.tri(mat1)
}

# MAKE FAKE DATA
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(sample(400)/400, 20, 20)
a <- m * lower.tri(m)
b <- sample(20)/21

# INITIALIZE VARS
add_prev <- matrix(rep(0, 200), 20, 20)
init_mat <- lower.tri(m) + diag(20)
overwrite_mat <- init_mat

for (i in 1:20) {
    overwrite_mat <- (pad_a(a, i) * pad_b(b, i) * pad_c(overwrite_mat, i)) + add_prev
    add_prev <- overwrite_mat
}


denom1 <- matrix(rep(b, times=20), 20, 20)
denom1 <- denom1 * lower.tri(denom1) + diag(20)
denom2 <- matrix(rep(b, each=20), 20, 20)
denom2 <- denom2 * lower.tri(denom2) + diag(20)

final <- ((overwrite_mat / denom1) - denom2) + diag(20)
final <- replace(final, is.nan(final), 0)
```

Output (just showing upper left (5,5) matrix)

```
 [,1]         [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]       
 [1,]   0.0000000   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000   
 [2,]  -0.5129073   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000   
 [3,]   0.6738060  -0.05926190  0.00000000  0.00000000   
 [4,]   9.2856557   5.97660268 -0.15059524  0.00000000   
 [5,]   0.1971807   0.01591345 -0.14775033 -0.08718254
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Really impressive solution.